# Add a binary to my path

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I have an executable. I want to execute the executable in terminal with name only like other commands.

I can put my executable in `/usr/local/bin` or I could add its `PATH` to `~/.bashrc`. Both will work.

What is better?  Is there  any difference?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For example let me assume, you have an executable `myscript`. You need to run it from a terminal as,

```
/path/to/myscript
```

**User level Change**

If you  add the `PATH` of that executable to `~/.bashrc`, you can run the executable with name only from anywhere ([Avinash Raj](https://askubuntu.com/a/440693/127327) already mentioned), as

```
myscript
```

But the change will be affected in **user level**. That means if you have any other user(s) they could not access the executable with name only. If they have proper permission they need to run the executable as,

```
/path/to/myscript
```

Also, you will not be able to run the script as **sudo** as it is not in `PATH` of root, To run as `sudo` you need to use,

```
sudo /path/to/myscript
```

**system level change**

If you put your script in `/usr/local/bin` it can be accessed system wide and for all users. In that case any user can run your executable as (subject to having proper permissions)

```
myscript
```

In that case you can run the executable as `sudo` also as,

```
sudo myscript
```

Now choose one way depending upon your need.

Answer (score 7):

If you put the executable file in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, then you will be able to run that program by only specifying the name (`your-program` instead of `/usr/local/bin/your-program`).

If you instead add the directory containing the program to the `~/.bashrc` file to the `PATH`, then any executable file present in that directory can be launched by only typing its name.

Comment: This information is false, you can stil launch the executable even if you are not in "that directory".

Comment: How is this false?, please explain a bit more.

Comment: Ok, I had a hard time reading your answer (and thereby made an error) so I edited it to remove the confusion and remoted the downvote. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: So, the question is: *What is better? Is there any difference?* You practically didn't say nothing more than the OP.

Comment: I answered for the OS's question but not in a brief format.

Answer (score 7):

Adding the location of the file to your `$PATH` variable in your `~/.bashrc` file will only allow you to execute from any location, whereas putting it in `/usr/bin/` will allow all users on your system to execute that file from any location.

Why is that? Because, your `~/.bashrc` file is only visible to you as a user. So all variable changes done are limited to you. Whereas, adding that file to `/usr/bin` will allow the file to remain there for all users and since `/usr/bin` is present in the `$PATH` variable unless someone removes it, will allow all users to execute it from any location.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement to @souravc answer...

For the "User level Change", instead of editing the `~/.bashrc` file you can simply create the directory `$HOME/bin/` and place your scripts in there.

The directory will be automatically added to the `PATH` (at least since Ubuntu 12.04) which means that you'll be able to run all the scripts/executables inside that directory with a simple:

```
myscript
```

Just my 2 cents. :)

PS- I tried to post this as a comment to @souravc answer, but I didn't have enough reputation. :-(